# "image" is not accessed - Pylance

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

Pyance is showing false warnings in certain functions.

[image]

Even the variable is used it still shows as it. For example in the above picture

- The varible `image` from line 1984 is accessed in line number 1986.
- The varible `image_obj` from line 1985 is accessed in line number 1991 and 1992.
- And similar cases on other lines too.

Can anyone help me figure why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

This problem cannot be reproduced with simple code. I think we can refer to [this case](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3225) on Github for a solution.

Perhaps Pylance analysis code exceeded the limit and some of the code was omitted.

In this case, patch `t.maxCodeComplexity=` in `.vscode/extensions/ms-python.vscode-pylance-%version%/dist/pyright.bundle.js` and increase the limit back to 1024 can solve it.